# How to send data to some other client when one client connects in Socket.io , Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on("event2", function(data) {
        sendToClient1(data, function(result){  
        io.to(socket.id).emit("emit_test" , JSON.stringify(data)); // this works
        });

        sendToClient2(data, function(result){  
        io.to(result).emit("emit_test" , JSON.stringify(data)); // this does not work
        });

    });

    sendToClient2:function(data, func){
        red_client.get(data, function(err, reply){
        console.log(reply);
        func(reply);
    });
});
```

Here the data will be username of second client whose socket id is stored in redis server . 
This is not working in my case . I cannot receive the emit data on second client ? What am I doing wrong in here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not used socket.on to catch emitted data from client.

Comment: In line number 2 I am using this to catch the data from client on server . "socket.on("event2", function(data) "